# How to add sum of the selected check box amount in web grid to show in the footer

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, webgrid

```
I am trying to use the Web Grid, i was able to bind the data to web grid and able to add check box select functionality to the web grid.

but in my grid one field is there called amount, when i am select check box in the web grid i have to do the sum of the amount column values similar to shopping basket.

but i am not getting the values of the webgrid.

   @model IEnumerable<JsonResultTest.Models.ShoppingBasketModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(source: Model, canPage: false, canSort: false);
}

@* Here I am going to add some css for better looks *@

<style type="text/css">
    table.gridtable {
        font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif;
        font-size: 11px;
        color: #333333;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-color: #666666;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

        table.gridtable th {
            border-width: 1px;
            padding: 8px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: #666666;
            background-color: #dedede;
        }

        table.gridtable td {
            border-width: 1px;
            padding: 8px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: #666666;
            background-color: #ffffff;
        }
</style>

<h2>Customer Data</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Webgrid", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div>
        @grid.GetHtml(
tableStyle: "gridtable",
htmlAttributes: new { id = "checkableGrid" },
columns: grid.Columns
(
        //Here I am going to add checkbox column
grid.Column(
format: @<text> <input type="checkbox" value="@item.BondLodgementAmount" name="ids" id="chk_check" /> </text>,
     header: "{checkall}"
     ),
       grid.Column("BondNumber", "Bond Number"),
       grid.Column("PropertyId", "Property Id"),
       grid.Column("TenancyAddress", "Tenancy Address"),
       //grid.Column("BondLodgementAmount", "Bond Lodgement Amount"),
       grid.Column("BondLodgementAmount", header: "BondLodgementAmount", format: @<text>@String.Format("{0:0.00}", (string)(@item.BondLodgementAmount))</text>, style: "price")
     )
     )
    </div>
    <div>


    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Get Selected Record" />
    </div>
}
@if (ViewBag.Message != null)
{
    <div>
        @ViewBag.Message
    </div>
}
@section Scripts{
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {




            //$('#ids').click(function () {
            //    alert(row);
            //    var ischecked = this.checked;
            //    $('#checkableGrid').find("input:checkbox").each(function () {
            //        this.checked = ischecked;
            //        var row = $(this).closest('tr'); // get the table row


            //       // var links = row.find('a'); // get the 3 hyperlinks
            //        //var teamName = links.eq(0).text();
            //        //var description = links.eq(1).text();
            //    });
            //});

            // 1st replace first column header text with checkbox

            $("#checkableGrid th").each(function () {

                if ($.trim($(this).text().toString().toLowerCase()) === "{checkall}") {
                    $(this).text('');
                    $("<input/>", { type: "checkbox", id: "cbSelectAll", value: "" }).appendTo($(this));
                    $(this).append("<span>Select All</span>");
                }
            });





            $("input[name='ids']").click(function () {
                var totalRows = $("#checkableGrid td :checkbox").length;

                var checked = $("#checkableGrid td :checkbox:checked").length;


                var total = 0;
                $('#grid .price').each(function () {
                    // total = total + parseFloat($(this)[0].innerHTML.toLocaleString());

                });
                $('tbody').append('<tr><td><b>Total</b></td><td><b>' + total.toFixed(2) + '</b></td></tr>');
                //var favorite = [];
                //favorite.push(checked.val());
                //var total = 0;
                  //  total += favorite[i] ;
             /*   $.each($("input[name='ids']:checked"), function () {
                    favorite.push($(this).val());
                    //total += favorite;
                    var total = 0;
                    for (var i = 0; i < favorite.length; i++) {
                        total += favorite[i] << 0;
                $('tbody').append('<tr><td><b>Total</b></td><td><b>' + total + '</b></td></tr>');         
                    }

                });*/

             //   alert("My favourite sports are: " + favorite.join(", "));

                if (checked == totalRows) {
                    $("#checkableGrid").find("input:checkbox").each(function () {
                        this.checked = true;
                    });
                }
                else {
                    $("#cbSelectAll").removeAttr("checked");
                }
            });

            $('#cbSelectAll').click(function () {
                var ischecked = this.checked;
                $('#checkableGrid').find("input:checkbox").each(function () {
                    this.checked = ischecked;
                    var row = $(this).closest('tr'); // get the table row
                    var links = row.find('a'); // get the 3 hyperlinks
                    var teamName = links.eq(0).text();
                    var description = links.eq(1).text();
                });
            });
                      ////2nd click event for header checkbox for select /deselect all
            //$("#cbSelectAll").live("click", function () {
            //    var ischecked = this.checked;
            //    $('#checkableGrid').find("input:checkbox").each(function () {
            //        this.checked = ischecked;
            //    });
            //});


            //3rd click event for checkbox of each row


        });
    </script>
}

Problem : 
        CheckAll          PhoneNumber  UAN      Add          Price

          Check            123455      ABCD     NewYork        100$
         Uncheck           123456      ABCD1    NewYork1       200$
          Check            123457      ABCD2    NewYork2       300$

**Assume here in the above grid 1,3 rows are checked so i have to display 100$+300$=400$**


**After struggle i was able to add almost all the functionality, but i am facing the problem while adding the new row, while clicking the check box every time it is creating new row, the problem is in the below code.**

     $('#grid .price').each(function () {
                        // total = total + parseFloat($(this)[0].innerHTML.toLocaleString());

                    });
                    $('tbody').append('<tr><td><b>Total</b></td><td><b>' + total.toFixed(2) + '</b></td></tr>');
```

can any body correct me which function i have to use to get the total for each click event. means if i click on one check box i have to get the amount value from that row in a lablel, if i click on other check box again, then the existing value should get added to the new value.

Comment: do i need to provide any other information?

Comment: Hello jquery experts.. any body is there??